# Run continuous custom application logic on server side. Entry point?

Tags: c#, silverlight, plugins, entry-point, web

I am creating some kind of a plug-in system. Currently I was using `WinForms` application to load the assemblies, using `Assembly.Load` and `Activator.CreateInstance`. The WinForms GUI was supposed to show only the names of the currently loaded assemblies (plugins).

There is a class in the library `PluginManager`, that instantiates and holds a list of all `IPlugin` implementors.

However, I now want to be able to access the list of plugins (their names only) from the `Silverlight` application.

I have a `Silverlight 4` application created in Visual Studio.

This added two projects:

- `MyProject` (SL 4 project)
- `MyProject.Web` (containing the .aspx startup page which runs the .xap file)

What I need is for the `PluginManager` and its instantiated plugins to be loaded not only during the silverlight page request (thru aspx page), but all the time, even if the user never opens the silverlight app in the browser. And I am confused as to what is the entry point of the .Web project. (in console app, I would put the code into the Main method, in WinForms in Loaded event handler, but I don't know where to start my "service" in this `.Web` project).

How does this work? Where should I instantiate my `PluginManager`? Is that `.Web` project short-lived only during the HTTP request or can it be run continuously?

Comment: It was made as a Silverlight Business Application project template, so VS generated both projects. So I guess it's an application. Not sure, though. How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Add Global.asax to MyProject.Web. And do that in Application_Start() method.
This method invokes only once when application is built.

If you need to run your PluginManager before application has been built, you should create a windows service which runs from your installer. This service will instantiate PluginManager.

Comment: You are talking about a windows service, right? What would then be the best way to talk to the service from the Global.asax. I don't think I fully understand the architecture.

Comment: You can create PluginManager in Application_Start() - but this method will be invoked only once, on first request to your web app. If PluginManager should be instantiated before first request, for instance, at once after install application you can create your own windows service. But I think solution with Global.asax will be appropriated for you

Comment: No, actually I guess I need the service, because the app should run even if no requests for a page are made. Now I just need to find a right way to communicate with my windows service from the SL application.